# Relation of the min of several exponential distributions, and the min of several gamma distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Note that I have taken a Probability Theory class (but only briefly mentioned that gamma distribution is the sum of exponential distributions) before, so somewhat rigorous explanations are fine for me. I have used generating functions before, but very limited.

Let $\forall{i},T_i$ be distributed as $exp(\lambda_i)$. Then let $T= \min\{T_1,...,T_n\}$, then $T$ has an exponential distribution with $\lambda = \sum_i^n{\lambda_i}$

Also, we know that $\sum_i^n{T_i}$ is exactly the gamma distribution with parameters $(n,\lambda)$.

My question is very specific (albeit I would be interested in a general proof too): Supposing we have $G_1,G_2$, both have gamma distributions with parameter $(2,\lambda)$, and we are interested in $G:=\min\{G_1,G_2\}$, is there an analog as to the exponential case?

Comment: I guess from your earlier notation with $\lambda$ in the minimum of the exponentails that you are in the "shape,rate" parametrization as opposed to the "shape,scale" parametrization, is that correct?

Comment: In any case the minimum of two $\Gamma(2,\lambda)$ variates is not Gamma distributed, since the PDF has an incomplete Gamma function term in it.